# Python: Force import to prefer .py over .so

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, cython, python-import

I have a situation where the same Python module is present in the same directory in two different versions; `mymodule.py` and `mymodule.so` (I obtain the latter from the first via Cython, but that's irrelevant to my question). When from Python I do

```
import mymodule
```

it always chooses `mymodule.so`. Sometimes I really want to import `mymodule.py` instead. I could temporarily move `mymodule.so` to another location, but that does not play well if I simultaneously have another Python instance running which needs to import `mymodule.so`.

The question is how to make `import` prefer `.py` files over `.so`, rather than vice versa?

Here's my thoughts on a solution:
I imagine performing some magic using [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) and possibly edit `sys.meta_path`. Specifically I see that `sys.meta_path[2]` holds `_frozen_importlib_external.PathFinder` which is used to import external modules, i.e. this is used for both `mymodule.py` and `mymodule.so`. If I could just replace this with a similar `PathFinder` which used the reverse ordering for file types, I would have a solution.

I'm using Python 3.7, if that affects the solution.

#### Edit

Note that simply reading in the source lines of `mymodule.py` and `exec`'ing them won't do, as `mymodule.py` may itself import other modules which again exist in both a `.py` and `.so` version (I want to import the `.py` version of these as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [these notes](https://www.dabeaz.com/modulepackage/ModulePackage.pdf) I came up with this. It's not too pretty, but it seems to work.

```
import glob, importlib, sys

def hook(name):
    if name != '.':
        raise ImportError()
    modnames = set(f.rstrip('.py') for f in glob.glob('*.py'))
    return Finder(modnames)
sys.path_hooks.insert(1, hook)
sys.path.insert(0, '.')

class Finder(object):
    def __init__(self, modnames):
        self.modnames = modnames
    def find_spec(self, modname, target=None):
        if modname in self.modnames:
            origin = './' + modname + '.py'
            loader = Loader()
            return importlib.util.spec_from_loader(modname, loader, origin=origin)
        else:
            return None

class Loader(object):
    def create_module(self, target):
        return None
    def exec_module(self, module):
        with open(module.__spec__.origin, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            code = f.read()
        compile(code, module.__spec__.origin, 'exec')
        exec(code, module.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution, that works just by tweaking the finders that the runtime generates by default. This uses hidden implementation details (`FileFinder._loaders`), but I've tested on CPythons 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from dataclasses import dataclass
from importlib.machinery import FileFinder
from importlib.abc import Finder
import sys
from typing import Callable


@dataclass
class PreferPureLoaderHook:
    orig_hook: Callable[[str], Finder]

    def __call__(self, path: str) -> Finder:
        finder = self.orig_hook(path)
        if isinstance(finder, FileFinder):
            # Move pure python file loaders to the front
            finder._loaders.sort(key=lambda pair: 0 if pair[0] in (".py", ".pyc") else 1)  # type: ignore
        return finder


@contextmanager
def prefer_pure_python_imports():
    sys.path_hooks = [PreferPureLoaderHook(h) for h in sys.path_hooks]
    sys.path_importer_cache.clear()
    yield
    assert all(isinstance(h, PreferPureLoaderHook) for h in sys.path_hooks)
    sys.path_hooks = [h.orig_hook for h in sys.path_hooks]
    sys.path_importer_cache.clear()

with prefer_pure_python_imports():
    ...
```